# Find the domain of $\sqrt{x^2-9}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$\sqrt{x^2-9}$$

I know that the domain of square root is greater than or equal to zero. I solve for when $x^2-9<0$ and get $x^2<9$. Now I get $x<-3$ and $x<3$. I know that the domain is $(-\infty,-3] \cup [3,\infty)$ The problem is I do not understand how the $x<3$ gets flipped to $x>3$, am I doing this step properly or is there another way to do it?

Comment: You need to solve for when $x^2-9\ge0$.  So you get $x^2\ge9$.  But when you take the square root of $x^2$, what happens??

Comment: Ultimately your answer is right, but the steps are not. The **bad** $x$ are the $x$ with $x^2\lt 9$, that is, with $-3\lt x\lt 3$. Now you can write down the good $x$ easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All other answers made a good survey to this question, but I'd like to note  some good points. When we have a function like $f(x)=\sqrt[n]{g(x)}$ while $n$ is even number so:

- $f(x)\geq 0$
- $g(x)\geq0$

And you see that @Brian's trying to show you that we have to make $x^2-9$ positive. Moreover a very simple effective rule as follows:

> $$x^2-a^2\geq 0\Longleftrightarrow x^2\geq a^2\Longleftrightarrow x\geq a\cup x\leq -a$$

This is what @Omno indicated. Here we have $a=3$.

Comment: I'll do it, Thanks.

Comment: @amWhy: God time Amy. :)

Answer (score 5):

You went a bit off track midway. Instead, let's rewrite $x^2-9<0$ as $(x+3)(x-3)<0.$ This will only be true when $x+3$ and $x-3$ are of opposite sign (why?), so since $x-3<x+3$ for all real $x,$ then we need to figure out when $x-3<0$ and $x+3>0$. Can you take it the rest of the way?

Comment: Could you explain why it's a mistake to add 9 and take the square root of both sides? Can you not take the square root of inequalities?

Comment: Well, you can. However, starting with $x^2<9$ and applying the square root to both sides, we get $$\sqrt{x^2}<\sqrt 9,$$ or equivalently, $$|x|<3.$$ The kicker, here, is that $\sqrt{x^2}=x$ for **non-negative** $x$ only. In general, the best we can say is that $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|.$

Comment: It's also worth noting that what you're calculating is the points that are ***not*** in the domain. The points in the domain are those $x$ such that $x^2\ge 9.$

Answer (score 4):

You need to have $x^2-9\ge 0$, not $x^2-9<0$. This is $(x-3)(x+3)\ge 0$, which is the case when

- one of $x-3$ and $x+3$ is $0$,
- both $x-3$ and $x+3$ are positive, or
- both $x-3$ and $x+3$ are negative.

In all other cases $(x-3)(x+3)$ is negative, which is precisely what you **don’t** want.

- The first of these happens when $x=3$ or $x=-3$.
- The second happens when $x>3$ and $x>-3$; of course if $x>3$, then automatically $x>-3$, so this happens when $x>3$.
- And the third happens when $x<3$ and $x<-3$; this time we notice that if $x<-3$, then automatically $x<3$, so this happens when $x<-3$.

Putting the pieces together, we see that $x^2-9\ge 0$ when $x\le -3$ or $x\ge 3$.

With practice, however, you should come to realize that if $a\ge 0$, then $x^2\ge a^2$ if and only if $|x|>\sqrt{a}$. Here that means that $|x|\ge 3$, which means that $x$ is at least as far away from $0$ as $3$ is, i.e., that $x\le -3$ or $x\ge 3$.

Comment: I am confused why you left out $x>-3$ in your fifth bullet point. Why don't you use $x>-3$ since it includes $x>3$?

Comment: @Steven: Because it doesn’t: $0>-3$, but $0\not>3$. If you know that $x>3$, then you know that $x>-3$, so the requirement that $x>-3$ is superfluous. If you know that $x>-3$, you do **not** know that $x>3$, so the requirement that $x>3$ is **not** superfluous.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$  This will help you to understand what is happening..

Answer (score 0):

You had a little bit of a mistake.  You were right when you said that $x$ is in the domain when
$$
x^2 \geq 9
$$
This, in turn, means that $x\color{red}\leq-3$ and $x\geq3$.  So, the domain of this function is $(-\infty,-3]\cup[3,\infty)$ as desired.

Comment: @AndréNicolas thank you.